# Using MapView within Fragment under Google Maps Android API v2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I got error when i using mapview within Fragment under APIV2

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

        // try {
               // MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        //    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // TODO handle this situation
        //    }


        mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);
        mMapView.onResume();

     //   try {
        //    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
     //   } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
     //       e.printStackTrace();
     //   }

        mMap = mMapView.getMap();
        return inflatedView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55,-4)).title("title"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

And here is my map.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    /> 



     <!-- 
<fragment
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
/>
    -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error happened at : **mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);****
Then if I uncommand

```
`// try {
               // MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        //    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // TODO handle this situation
        //    }`
```

**The error will be here:GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException 
it says unresearchable catch block for this**

Need someone for help

Comment: have you generated API key

Comment: Well if the code runs in the catch statment of the `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException` it just means that the Play Services are too old or not installed on that device.

Comment: I Already generated API key

Comment: the Play Service is up to date in HTC ONE running 4.4.2

Comment: I have another device (Nexus 7,Android 4.4.2,Parandroid ) also FC when i run mapFrament

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of code:

```
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
```

to:

```
}catch (Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: then error happened at :  mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); TAG:android Runtime